# How h264 NAL units to be corectly sampled inside fragmented MP4

Tags: video, video-streaming, mp4, h.264, fmp4

Having a stream of NAL units of types `[5 [1]+]+`, how to correctly reference them in samples field of `trun` box of frgmented mp4 so they would decode and present correctly, without stuttering?

The main issue here is that not every time single NAL unit maps to single I/P/B frame, ofen multiple NAL units are representing same frame, so it is not clear if each MP4 sample should be referencing each NAL unit or a group of NAL units related to the same I/P/B frame.

In case i should reference each NAL unit in separate MP4 sample, what about DTS/PTS/CTS? How should they be different if it is all the same frame?

In case i should reference group of NAL units related to the same frame in one MP4 sample, is same `frame_num` for consecutive NAL units of same NAL type defines them as related to the same frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "Frame" called a "Access Unit" (or AU) in h.264 contains 1 more more NALU. The trun encodes each AUs size, this includes all NALUs for that AU. NALUs do not have timestamps, AUs do.

Comment: It is not of question whether to put multiple NAL units into `trun` box or single one, my question is of `trun` samples field: should single sample contain single NAL or complete frame.

Comment: One sample is one frame, which is one or more nalu.